# wix common ui dialog - how to use the same dialog more than once in single MSI

Tags: wix

I am using Wix::Extensions::CommonUi from AppSecInc.

I need to deploy two databases in my MSI and need to collect the db connection information from the user for both databases.

I would like to utilize DbCreateCredDlg dialog.

```
<UI>

....

<DialogRef Id="DbCreateCredDlg" />

<!- use DbCreateCredDlg for database 1 ->

<!- use DbCreateCredDlg for database 2 ->

...

</UI>
```

Is there any way I can use the this dialog more than once in the same MSI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you should pull the sources of that dialog to include in your sources and modify it accordingly. For instance, add a condition when the Next button of this dialog returns it to self for database 2 data. You'll need to preserve the data in the properties tied to dialog controls before prompting the user to enter the data for database 2.

So, the Next button will do the following (just behavior algorithm):

- if DB=1, preserve entered data for database1
- set DB=2
- show this dialog again
- if DB=2, preserve entered data for database2
- show next dialog in sequence

The similar thing should be done for Back button of that dialog.

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. One question though, How can I use your solution if I want to add the "selectdb" dialog for both databases? SelectDb will be displayed first and then cred dialog. Thanks again..

Comment: Well, I don't think it would differ too much... Just instead of repeating a single dialog in the sequence you'll have to repeat both. Anyway, it is all about specifying correct actions and conditions Next/Back buttons... Start from anything simple (test project), and later on when it proves to work, move to your real solution.

Comment: Thank you, Although it does not look straightforward; I think your solution is the only workaround to the problem.